# How to get consistent stroke thickness when zooming grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

I've noticed that when I am using the *Grease pencil* with a placement other than "view" the thickness stays the same thickness based on the view in a way that it isn't effected by it's perceived distance from the camera.

Is there a way to make the stroke thickness remain consistent with its distance from the camera? And as a side note, is there a way to change the thickness to something larger than 10px?

Comment: As for thinkness larger than 10px, you can directlly input the desired number.

Comment: @Allosteric the problem is that the thickness is not consistent the the 3D environment, its consistant to the camera so when you zoom the line appears to be getting thinner relative to everything

Comment: my answer was just meant for the side note. I myself was curious on the main question (and set the bounty) so I didn't want others to be bothered with >10px lines.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can get something like this, by enabling "Volumetric Strokes" in your grease pencil palette.
[image: Volumetric Strokes Checkbox]

This creates the following effect (reduced opacity for clarity, volumetric is on the right hand side).
[image: Volumetric Strokes Comparison]

The sampled points can be increased by adding subdivision (default is 0 for basic brush) under the stroke quality section in the grease pencil panel. Increased subdivision is only applied to new strokes though.
[image: Stroke subdivisions]

The volumetric strokes retain their size, regardless of viewport zoom.
[image: Stroke Comparison]

Lastly, grease pencil *objects* are coming to blender 2.80, which will support proper scaling.